# PowerShell, Where-Object (Match square brackets) (regex)

Tags: powershell, match, square-bracket

I have a .txt file that the system writes hostnames to; either the IPv4 address or computer name, pending the circumstances.  To help parse the file, the system puts the IP Address or host name within square brackets.

Example: `some text [192.168.1.1] some text`

Now I want to pull the IP address or computer name out of the file with:

`Get-Content -Path .\somefile.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match "[*]"}`

but when I run this, I get nothing (I think due to the wildcard and -match, might need to use -like?)

Then if I try just a single square bracket:

`Get-Content -Path .\somefile.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match "["}`

I get the following error:

`parsing "[" = Unterminated [] set.`

Any ideas?  Am I running into a PowerShell limitation with square brackets and just need to choose a different character to help parse?  Suggestions?

Comment: if you want to match regex reserved characters like the brackets, you need to escape them. [*grin*] you can either do it manually with  a slash character before each such char OR use the `[regex]::Escape()` method to do it for you.

Comment: escape the square brackets: `{$_ -match "\[.*\]"}`

Answer (score 5):

`-match` uses regular expression syntax: [About Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6)

You need to escape special symbols

```bsh
C:\> "some text [192.168.1.1] some text" -match "\[*\]"
True
```

To get the IP address use capture groups and `$Matches` built-it variable.

```bsh
C:\> "some text [192.168.1.1] some text" -match "\[(.*)\]"
True
C:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              192.168.1.1
0                              [192.168.1.1]

C:\> $matches[1]
192.168.1.1
```

Or named capture groups.

```bsh
C:\> "some text [192.168.1.1] some text" -match "\[(?<IpFromFile>.*)\]"
True
C:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
IpFromFile                     192.168.1.1
0                              [192.168.1.1]

C:\> $matches['IpFromFile']
192.168.1.1
```